# How does the trait "Backtracker" work?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

In The Darkest Dungeon there is a trait named "[Backtracker](http://darkestdungeon.gamepedia.com/Back_Tracker)" with the following description:

> No Stress penalty when walking backwards

Does this refer to literally walking backwards within a hallway after having walked forward? (by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>)

Or does this refer to entering and passing through a hallway again that you went through before?

Also, which of these result in additional stress, as the trait description implies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the Backtracker trait and the additional stress penalty refer to walking backwards within a hallway after having walked forward.  I couldn't find an official source for this, but it's relatively easy to verify manually that walking backwards through an entire area causes more stress than exiting, reentering, and walking forwards in the opposite direction.  (If you want to verify this, I recommend using throwaway characters)

Comment: So why exactly would ever want to go backwards in a hallway? Unless I miss some fundamental game principle, that trait is utterly useless.

Comment: On certain maps, it could be useful to go backwards (so that you can try an alternate route) if the path is blocked and you have no shovel, or if you only wanted to grab a treasure or item in the first 1/4 of the path and then return.  Without the trait, you are probably better off plowing forward (even with the penalty for clearing a path without a shovel).  That being said, I agree that it is not a very useful trait.